# sql join or union query on booking system

Tags: sql, join, union

Im not very experienced when it comes to joins,unions,ON-s etc
but I have a school and I need to select customer names from two
tables, vip and regular customers.

Im trying both ways but unfortunately nothing really works:
//1

```
SELECT Hotel_Rooms.Book_From, Hotel_Rooms.Book_To, Hotel_Rooms.[Book_To]-[Book_From] AS Booked_Days, Hotel_Rooms.[Price_Per_Night]*[Booked_Days] AS Price, Reg_Customers.Cust_name
FROM Reg_Customers
UNION
SELECT Hotel_Rooms.Book_From, Hotel_Rooms.Book_To, Hotel_Rooms.[Book_To]-[Book_From] AS Booked_Days, Hotel_Rooms.[Price_Per_Night]*[Booked_Days] AS Price, Vip_Customers.Cust_name
FROM Vip_Customers
INNER JOIN Hotel_Rooms ON Reg_Customers.Cust_ID = Hotel_Rooms.Cust_ID && Vip_Customers.Cust_ID = Hotel_Rooms.Cust_ID
ORDER BY Hotel_Rooms.[Price_Per_Night]*[Booked_Days] DESC;
```

//2

```
SELECT Hotel_Rooms.Book_From, Hotel_Rooms.Book_To, Hotel_Rooms.[Book_To]-[Book_From] AS Booked_Days, Hotel_Rooms.[Price_Per_Night]*[Booked_Days] AS Price, Reg_Customers.Cust_name, Vip_Customers.Cust_name
FROM Reg_Customers, Vip_Customers
INNER JOIN Hotel_Rooms ON Reg_Customers.Cust_ID = Hotel_Rooms.Cust_ID && Vip_Customers.Cust_ID = Hotel_Rooms.Cust_ID
ORDER BY Hotel_Rooms.[Price_Per_Night]*[Booked_Days] DESC;
```

None of the queries works to select, join tables properly. Can you please help?
table schemes if these help

Rooms  { Rooms_ID, Cust_ID, Room_Capacity, Available, Book_Time, Book_Price_Per_Night, Book_From, Book_To }

regular customers {Cust_ID, Cust_Name, Cust_Phone, Cust Card}
vip               {Cust_ID, Cust_Name, Cust_Phone, Cust Card}

Thank you.
If you could provide a working query, either #1 or #2 version that'd be great,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach is better, but you are making a mistake.   You can join tables like this:

```
from table1, table2
where table1.id = table2.id
```

or like this (which is better)

```
from table1 join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

but you can't use both techniques in the same query.  That's what you have in your second example.

**Edit Starts here**

reading your question again, the union query is a better approach.  However, you made two mistakes here:

```
FROM Vip_Customers
INNER JOIN Hotel_Rooms ON Reg_Customers.Cust_ID = Hotel_Rooms.Cust_ID 
&& Vip_Customers.Cust_ID = Hotel_Rooms.Cust_ID
ORDER BY Hotel_Rooms.[Price_Per_Night]*[Booked_Days] DESC;
```

The first mistake was in logic.  You are selecting from vip customers but joining from the regular customers table.  The second mistake is with syntax.  Replace "&&" with "and".  No RDBMS of which I am aware supports "&&".

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, Im feeling a bit dumb now though, actually Im joining 3 tables, vip customers, regular customers and rooms, how can I achieve it using your method? Thanks.

Comment: OR better yet, consdering the code I posted, is there any way you could propose a solution using that code. If not no worries, I dont want to embarras you. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

not knowing your database is a bit tricky, but based on what you've provided this union/sort may work

```
{ 
    SELECT hr.Book_From, hr.Book_To, hr.[Book_To]-[Book_From] AS Booked_Days, hr.[Price_Per_Night]*[Booked_Days] AS Price, rc.Cust_name
    FROM Reg_Customers rc
    LEFT JOIN Hotel_Rooms AS hr ON rc.Cust_ID = hr.Cust_ID
} UNION {
    SELECT hr.Book_From, hr.Book_To, hr.[Book_To]-[Book_From] AS Booked_Days, hr.[Price_Per_Night]*[Booked_Days] AS Price, vc.Cust_name
    FROM Vip_Customers vc
    LEFT JOIN Hotel_Rooms AS hr ON vc.Cust_ID = hr.Cust_ID
}
ORDER BY [Price_Per_Night]*[Booked_Days] DESC;
```